# $L^1$ norm for a product of cosines

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, analytic-number-theory, fourier-analysis

Let $k$ be an integer and consider the function
$$
f(t)=\prod_{i=1}^{k} \cos(3^{i-1}\pi t).
$$
I'm interested in finding bounds for $\int_{0}^{1}|f(t)|dt$ in terms of $k$. The first idea that comes to mind is using Hölder's inequality:
$$
\int_{0}^{1} |f(t)| dt \le \prod_{i=1}^{k} \bigg(\int_{0}^{1}|\cos(3^{i-1}\pi t)|^k dt \bigg)^{\frac{1}{k}}
$$
Now, using the periodicity of $|\cos(3^{i-1}\pi t)|$, note that
$$
\int_{0}^{1}|\cos(3^{i-1}\pi t)|^k dt =\int_{0}^{1}|\cos(\pi t)|^k dt, 
$$
so that
$$
\int_{0}^{1} |f(t)|dt \le \int_{0}^{1}|\cos(\pi t)|^k dt,
$$
and I'm sure there should be some results for the moments of cosine. However, computationally this doesn't seem like a good bound. Is there a better way to do this? The reason I'm interested in this function is because it appears in the context of the Fourier transform of a certain set of integers.

Comment: Your bound will give $\int_0^1 |f(t)|dt \lesssim \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$ which is indeed very weak since you don't use the lacunarity of $3^j$. A much simpler and much better bound one can get from the simple inequality $||f||_{L^1} \le ||f||_{L^2}$ and that $||f||_{L^2}$ we can compute explicitly, it is $\sqrt{2}^{-k}$, so we get an exponential upper bound.  Also obviously we have some exponential lower bound, albeit with a different exponent. My intuition tells me that the correct exponent should be $\exp(\int_0^1 \log |\cos(\pi x)|) = \frac{1}{2}$, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Yes, that is a much better bound but still I agree with your intuition. I also think the best exponent possible should be 1/2, but I wouldn't know how to prove this. One possible approach is to use the techniques from Maynard on his work on primes with missing digits and show that the exponent will be the eigenvalue of a certain matrix. However, since this function is so explicit I was thinking maybe there's an easier approach

Comment: In fact, my intuition is wrong. Specifically, by induction it is not hard to show that $I_{n+1} \ge \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}I_n$, thus $I_k \ge \sqrt{3}^{-k}$, because $\min_{x\in \mathbb{R}} |\cos(x)| + |\cos(x+\frac{2\pi}{3})| +|\cos(x+\frac{4\pi}{3})| = \sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Oh I see now you meant the lower bound. I still think that for the upper bound the integral is $O(1/2^k)$

Comment: @Itachi: maybe I'm missing something, but an upper bound of $2^{-k}$ is not compatible with a lower bound of $3^{-k/2}$.

Comment: @AlekseiKulikov Why not write down an answer with details, even though partial? It is interesting what you are saying.

Comment: @AnuragSahay yeah you're right, it is not compatible, my mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I was asked to in the comments, let me record here some very simple observations. They boil down to the following inequality: for all $k \ge N$ we have

$$I_{k - N} \min_{x\in \mathbb{R}} h_N(x) \le I_k \le I_{k-N} \max_{x\in \mathbb{R}} h_N(x),$$
where $I_k$ is the integral $\int_0^1 |f_k(t)|dt$ from the OP (I write subscript $k$ to avoid confusion), and $h_N(x) = \frac{1}{3^N}\sum_{j = 0}^{3^N-1}\left|f_N\left(x + \frac{j}{3^N}\right)\right|$.

Indeed, by the change of variables and/or periodicity we have

$$I_{k-N} = \int_0^1 |f_{k-N}(t)|dt = \int_0^1 |f_{k-N}(3^Nt)|dt.$$

To get $f_k(t)$ from $f_{k-N}(3^Nt)$ we have to multiply by the first $N$ cosine factors. But the idea is that if we replace $t$ with $t + \frac{j}{3^N}$ the value of $f_{k-N}(3^Nt)$ doesn't change. So, we can add all this points (considered modulo $1$) together and get
$$I_k = \int_0^1 h_N(t)|f_{k-N}(3^Nt)|dt,$$
from which we get the bounds I claimed in the beginning.

Applying this for $N = 1$ (and using deus ex machina aka Wolfram Alpha to find the minimal and maximal value) we get
$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}I_{k-1} \le I_k \le \frac{2}{3} I_{k-1},$$
so $\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)^k \le I_k \le \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k$. Note that the upper bound is already better than the one from my earlier comment with $L^1-L^2$ norm estimate since $\frac{2}{3} < \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. Using $N = 2$ provably gives even better bounds but only marginaly and I can't compute them explicitly.

It is reasonable to conjecture that, as we slowly tend $N$ to infinity, in this way we can get the optimal exponent, that is
$$\lim_{N\to \infty} \left(\min_{x\in \mathbb{R}} h_N(x)\right)^{1/N} = \lim_{N\to \infty} \left(\max_{x\in \mathbb{R}} h_N(x)\right)^{1/N} = c,$$
but I don't know how to prove it and what the value of $c$ should be (at the risk of being once again wrong let me conjecture that $c = \int_0^1 |\cos(\pi t)|dt = \frac{2}{\pi}$).

Comment: Thank you........

Comment: The value of $c$ that you suggest would correspond to the classical heuristics that lacunary function systems behave like independent random variables. I'm not sure if this applies here. Fouvry and Mauduit studied the problem in this post, but for sin instead of cos and 2 instead of 3 (I don't know if that makes a real difference). They proved the existence of a limit, but couldn't calculate the precise value (but it's larger than 2/pi). See E. Fouvry & C. Mauduit. Sommes des chiffres et nombres presque premiers. Math. Ann., 305(3):571–599, 1996. Cf. also https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.06738.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea (from the work of Maynard on primes with missing digits) to bound this integral is as follows: Since $t\in [0,1]$, we expand $t$ in base 3 as $t=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} t_i/3^i$, where $t_i\in \{0,1,2\}$. Now, note that
$$
3^{i-1}t= \mbox{Integer} + \frac{t_i}{3}+\frac{t_{i+1}}{3^2}+u_i, 
$$
where $u_i \in [0,1/3^2]$. Therefore, since $|\cos(3^{i-1}\pi t)|$ is periodic with period $1$, then
$$
f(t) \le \prod_{i=1}^{k-1} G(t_i,t_{i+1}),
$$
where
$$
G(a,b)=\sup_{u\in[0,1/3^2]}\bigg|\cos\big(\pi\big(\frac{a}{3}+\frac{b}{3^2}+u\big)\big)\bigg|.
$$
Now, consider the $3\times 3$ matrix defined at the $i,j$ entry by $M[i,j]=G(i-1,j-1)$ for $i,j=1,2,3$. Then, it is possible to show via the Perron Frobenius theorem (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.01041 for details) that
$$
\int_{0}^{1}|f(t)|dt \ll \big(\frac{\lambda}{3}\big)^k,
$$
where $\lambda$ is the largest eigenvalue of the matrix. Intuitively, we are approximating $f(t)$ by the value at the first two digits that matter in the expansion. A numerical computation reveals that $\lambda\approx 2.19429$. If instead of approximating by the first two decimals we instead approximate by the first 5 decimals, say
$$
3^{i-1}t= \mbox{Integer} + \frac{t_i}{3}+\frac{t_{i+1}}{3^2}+\frac{t_{i+2}}{3^3}+\frac{t_{i+3}}{3^4}+\frac{t_{i+4}}{3^5}+u_i, 
$$
where $u_i\in[0,1/3^5]$ and then we consider certain $3^4\times 3^4$ matrix, then it's possible to show that
$$
\int_{0}^{1}|f(t)|dt \ll \big(\frac{1.94884}{3}\big)^k,
$$
and again the 1.94884 comes from the maximal eigenvalue of that matrix. It would be interesting to consider the sequence of eigenvalues and conjecture what the limit is. For 10 digits, the value is approximately 1.94495.